# Этимология слова "дебелый"

Tags: этимология

"Дебелый" — массивный, в теле. А как это слово образовалось? От какого корня?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Дебелый Искон. Суф. производное от той же основы, что и доба «пора, время», добрый, удобный. Искон. добелый (известное еще в диалектах) > дебелый в результате межслоговой ассимиляции о-е в е-е, ср. ребенок < робенок, см. ребенок, раб. Дебелый буквально — «находящийся в поре, большой». Ср. добрый.

По школьному этимологическому словарю русского языка.